# Is there a known defect in enzyme, react-dom/test-tools, or jsdom that effects clientHeight?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, enzyme, jsdom, react-dom

I'm having an issue where `clientHeight` is `undefined` instead of the actual height of the DOM element.  This code **works as expected in the browser**.

**Component**

```
class MyWidget extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = { contentHeight: 0 };
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        this.setState(() => ({
            contentHeight: nextProps.open ? this.content.firstChild.clientHeight : 0
        }));
    }

    render() {
        const { controlId, open, trigger, children } = this.props;
        return (
            <div>
                <button tabIndex="0" aria-controls={controlId}>
                    { cloneElement(trigger, { open }) }
                </button>
                <div
                    id={controlId}
                    ref={(element) => {
                        this.content = element;
                    }}
                    aria-hidden={open}
                    style={{ maxHeight: this.state.contentHeight }}
                >
                    { cloneElement(children, { open }) }
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

However, when mounting the component and simulating a prop change, the `clientHeight` of the child `div` reports `undefined`.

**Unit Test**

```
// Arrange
const wrapper = mount(
    <MyWidget trigger={<span>click me</span>} open={false}>
        <div style={{ height: 90, padding: 5 }}>Lorum Ipsum</div>
    </MyWidget>
);

// Act
wrapper.setProps({ open: true });

// Assert
expect(wrapper.children('div').prop('style')).to.have.property('maxHeight', 100);

// Result
AssertionError: expected { maxHeight: undefined } to have a property 'maxHeight' of 100, but got undefined
```

I'm not entirely convinced that enzyme is the cause of this since it feels like its related to the underlying `react-dom/test-tools` and/or `jsdom`.  I've added a note on an [enzyme discussion](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/1434) since I'd appreciate some help in debugging this further.

Answer (score 1):

`jsdom` only provides a DOM -- it doesn't render your content visually. Therefore elements don't have width or height.

Because you have set the `maxHeight` using `firstChild.clientHeight` the value ends up being `undefined` because defining `clientHeight` would require visual rendering.

If you need to validate height or width in your test code, you may want to try out PhantomJS or headless Chrome -- headless browsers that are capable of rendering content visually.